# python os.path.isdir() is slow on windows

Tags: python, windows

We are experiencing really slow performance with os.path.isdir() method on windows. 
The same function under osx is running in 0.3 sec vs 1.8 for windows when checking a lot of files.

Is there an alternative to os.path.isdir() that would be faster?

Comment: Windows v. OS X is quite vague.  What hardware, what OS version of each, what other programs are running, etc.?

Comment: Python uses `stat` for both OS X and Windows to implement `isdir`. I wonder whether `stat` is slower on Windows than on real unix-y systems

Comment: @Eli: Probably yes because there is no single source on Windows to fill a Unix-like `stat` structure. The `stat` function is only a wrapper around several Windows functions that all need to be called even if only one piece of information is requested. `isdir` should use the `GetFileAttributes` API function instead.

Comment: FYI I've created a Python issue (http://bugs.python.org/issue11583) to track this

Comment: FYI #2: this was recently fixed and will appear in the next 2.7 and 3.2 releases - see the issue linked above for details

Comment: I just revisited this post and noticed the fix. Thank Eli for the fix.

Answer (score 2):

I think the quickest way to check on Windows is to call [`GetFileAttributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944%28VS.85%29.aspx). You could try this through ctypes and see if it is any faster.

If it is not faster then you'll probably just have to suck it down. And if it is faster then you have your solution.

Comment: It doesn't seem faster.

using fileAttr = win32file.GetFileAttributes(p)
and checking for the attribute if fileAttr & win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY:

give similar results.  It really looks like I will have to suck it down.

Or try to do some ugly hack looking for file extensions, but that will be so ugly.